# New file from existing in same Git repo

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to git, is there a "git way" to do this?

I want to have two versions of the same code available at the same time, both related to the same project.

Say I have code for a robot. I start by programming the bare minimum to get it working. Then, I add two different functionalities for it, which share the first piece of code, but exist independent of each other. I want to have access to both of these at all times. The robot has other files, which do not differ for each of the functionalities, but must also be updatable.

I've understood that if I just branch, the whole repository gets branched, meaning I'd always have to make changes to the other files twice. Is this right?

The simplest way to do this would be to just manually copy and rename the "bare minimum" file that needs to be duplicated, but this wouldn't retain the file's history, would it?

I feel like I'm missing some crucial piece of info on the workflow.

Comment: you want the copy of only one file or some other files also??
please do share for what purpose you are doing this?

Comment: @SyamPillai Sorry for the confusion. The project has many files, but only one of these needs to be in two versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the "core" code and "robot-specific" code independently, then you can use submodules. Make two projects (and git repos) for both robots, separate all "core" code into a separate git repository and add it to both projects as a git submodule.

You will then be able to open both projects in your editor or IDE and change the core code in any of them. Once you change it, make a commit in the submodule, push to remote and then pull to remote in the other project.

```
cd project1/core
# saving changes made in core code of project1
git add .
git commit -m'added foo and bar'
git push
cd ..
#moving project1 to the new core's commit
git add core
git commit -m'updated core'

cd ../project2/core
#updating core at project 2
git pull
cd ..
# moving project2 to the new core's commit
git add core
git commit -m'updated core'
```

I highly recommend that you write unit-tests and run them every time you make a core change. Since you change code that is used in several projects, you have more chances to break something with every introduced change.

> I've understood that if I just branch, the whole repository gets branched, meaning I'd always have to make changes to the other files twice. Is this right?

Yes, it is. Branching is not a convenient way to have two independent versions of your code. You'd have to merge or rebase every time you want to share changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the existing files into another and want to update both files once in a stable state, It's better to branch out and merge the code once you want to update

`$ git checkout -b new_branch`

this code will create a new branch named `new_branch` and copy all current files into `new_branch`. All the changes made after this will reflect only on `new_branch`

once you want to update the prev_branch (where you worked on before. eg:master) you can checkout to that branch and merge your code

```
$ git checkout prev_branch
$ git merge new_branch
```

now the changes made on `new_branch` will also reflect in `prev_branch`

Comment: Wouldn't merging always also affect the functionality file (the file that I need two versions of) that needs to stay separate between the branches? The final goal is to have a project that has, in addition to many "normal" files, have two different files (or two versions of a file that are easily accessible) that started as one file but separated at a point in the process.

Comment: No man, with this after merging both files will be same. Now I got your problem. lemme think :)

Answer (score 0):

- You need to create and work on branches.
  This is what branches are for in git

```
$ This is how you checkout new branch
# checkout new branch based upon the current branch 
git checkout -b <new branch name>
```

---

> If I create a new branch, do I have to copy that files; Or are they copied automatically if I create a new branch?

The new branch is a **FULL** copy to the current branch.
In order to understand why you need to know what is branch in git.

---

#### ***`What is branch in GIT?`***

A branch in Git is simply a **lightweight movable** pointer to commit.
[Here](https://backlogtool.com/git-guide/en/stepup/stepup1_1.html) is a very short and simple post about it

#### In other words:

Branch in git is simply a pointer to a commit.
As you can see in the image below (taken from the post mentioned above), all the branches are pointing to commit B + the delta which was added to them.

When you create branch git creates a file and writing the commit id to this file.

[image]

> I want to have access to both of these at all times.

This is what's the `checkout -b` does - switch you to the new branch which allows you to work on multiple "views" of the same content.

[image]

---

Another way to work on multiple branches on the same time is to use `worktree`.

## ***`git worktree`***

Git worktree was introduced in 2007 under the `contrib` folder in git repo and was called `new-workdir`.

In **git V2.5** it was exposed in git as `worktree` and it allow you to have multiple instances of the same repository across different folders.

for example:

```
# Open another "parallel" repository which allow you to work 
# simultaneously on X several branches on the same time. 
# You can have different branch checked out on each worktree

git worktree add <second path>
```

will create another folder on your computer which allow you to work on different branch simultaneously.

---